# Did the Ikshvakus feed on Flesh?

Tags: ramayana, rama, dasharatha

Hindu mythology have illustrated several times, how kings (Dashratha in Ramayana), go for hunting. The purpose of hunting has always/mostly been to enjoy the sport and obtain the skins of the animals like the Tigers/Lions.

But when they go for hunting a deer, with not much value for its skin... was the purpose to feast on it ?

This would also mean, that Meat-eating was acceptable at that time.

Comment: Do you mean "Ikshvaku"?

Comment: Yeah it does :)

Comment: Is your question about all kings or Ikshvakus in particular?

Comment: Its generally about all kings who hunted during the era of Lord Ram.